# 2 way Binding Nuxt.js

Tags: data-binding, nuxt.js, state, vuex

I'm trying to find a pattern that I can use that will allow me to update the State on input. I've tried several patterns including the get set method that is in the official docs, but I can't seem to get anything to work. I can get changes in the state to show on my page with an {{email}} but not the other way around when filling out a form. I'd appreciate any solutions at this point.

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <BaseInput placeholder="Email" type="text" :value="email" @input="updateEmail" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: {
    BaseInput,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      email: (state) => state.email,
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    updateEmail(email) {
      this.$store.commit('updateEmail', email)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`index.js`

```js
export const state = () => ({
  email: '',
})

export const mutations = {
  updateEmail(state, payload) {
    state.email = payload
  },
}
```

Comment: can you explain more? you want your state be updated with your input and vice versa, your input be filled (updated) with your state, right? have you tried `watch` hook??

Comment: What is not working? Please check your vue devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for the eventListener, you'll get the whole Event object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

If you want to use only the value of the field, you need to use

```js
this.$store.commit('updateEmail', email.target.value)
```

---

PS, some points to take into consideration:

- try to put more effort into formatting when posting your question
- do not use `mutations` but rather `actions` (core thing in Vuex)
- either use only the helpers (`mapState`, `mapActions` etc...) or direct Vuex (`$store.state`, `$store.commit` etc...) try to not mix both

Comment: Thank you I'll put more effort in the future for sure. I just saw the same solution you provided in the Fullstack Vue 3 book just before going to bed lol. I'll try it out later but should work since several sources give me the same answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be due to the v-modal not being directly on the input but a custom input instead. To fix this I made a slot in my custom input and wrapped it around a regular input to reveal the base input in my component.